# flexible membership billing

Tags: civimember

I have a series of different memberships in CiviCRM, currently with yearly billing for each. Each membership is currently set to auto renew.

The client has requested that a client might pay for these memberships monthly, or quarterly or yearly. I've looked to change the membership to a monthly membership, and using pricesets, enable 3 and 12 months as number of terms.

Unfortunately, as the membership is set to auto renew:
"You can include auto-renew membership choices for only one price field in a price set. Another field in this set already contains one or more auto-renew membership options."

The auto renew functionality has been turned on, as the memberships are set to continually renew but not use a payment processor. The records are being exported to another system, which generates the invoices.

Do I need to create monthly, quarterly and yearly options for each membership? Is there a better way to create the one membership, but have flexible pricing options which keep renewing after every period.

---

Since posting this question I found there is a bug in 4.6 and 4.7 of CiviCRM where you can't create a membership with auto renew in a price set - no matter what - not even one. This should be resolved in 4.7.5 (with about two lines of code). This allows you to keep a single membership and have different renewal periods at the same time.. and keep the reporting simplified, so the membership reporting will continue to show one membership.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18050
//If price set field is already present with auto-renew option then, it will restrict for adding another price set field with auto-renew option.
if ($dao->N == 0)
{ return 0; }

Comment: that issue was fixed for 4.7.3. If you are proposing an addition fix to a similar problem, please reopen the issue and comment on it, attaching your patch. Thanks for helping with improving CiviCRM!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create three membership one for monthly, Quarterly and yearly which will solve the problem

If you need all the frequency in a single membership then you have to handle this by creating a custom field linked with membership which will hold the frequency value and whenever we create a membership or renew a membership you should calculate the end date of the membership based on the frequency using hooks and update the membership record manually - that should solve the problem - I guess this helps!

Comment: Thanks. The client doesn't want the membership report to show every different combination of membership though. It's a good default option though.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, not the best, is to create a separate page for each type of membership, and through menus or an overview page direct users to the right one for the type of membership they want to buy.