# Advice on structuring tuition payment plans. Membership? Contribution?

Tags: civimember, price-sets, cividiscount

I have an annual tuition total that some parents pay in one installment, some in two, and some in 10 monthly payments. This past year, we set it up as a pledge that parents worked towards with contributions on a contribution page, but as I set up for next year I think it might be more effectively tracked through CiviMember, perhaps with price-sets? I would also like to be able to use the CiviDiscount extension in the tuition payments, and have some way of allowing parents to contribute to a scholarship fund on the same page.

Does CiviMember allow payments on an installment plan?
Does CiviDiscount work with the above answer?
What setup would you recommend for this use case?

Comment: in another answer someone (Joanne?) suggested doing different membership types for the various payment options. maybe give that an explore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of this one [flexible membership billing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/flexible-membership-billing) where Ramesh suggests using different membership types to accommodate the various payment options.

Comment: This is a bit awkward in setup, but it totally works! Marking as accepted. thanks for the help! :)